# If (serial.available()) conditional statement

Tags: arduino-uno

I am very new to Arduino and I have a question I would like to clarify on Serial.Available()

According to Arduino documentation, Available() returns the number of bytes that are stored in the buffer, ready to be read. Why then, both If function below works, when there are data in the buffer? For Scenario A, it appears to me that there is no conditional statement, how then, would the IF function evaluates to TRUE?

Scenario A: IF(Serial.Available())

compare with

Scenario B: IF(Serial.Available()>0)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mind the case: neither `IF` nor `serial` or `Available` exist.

Comment: the do the same thing; the 2nd is a pedantic long-hand way of writing it more explicitly

Answer (score 1):

In C, 0 is false and anything else is true. So if Serial.available() returns 0 it is considered false. If it returns 7, 23, 44, etc it is considered true.

Comment: But it is bad programming. It should be "if(Serial.available()>0)". The Serial.available does not return a boolean, but an integer. Therefor it should be tested against an integer. Off-topic: was there something with 'bool' and 'boolean' ?

Comment: @jot Boolean doesn't actually exist. There's a typedef in C++ (and in "stdbool.h" for C) that links it to an unsigned char. 0 is false, anything not 0 is true. There is absolutely nothing "bad" about it.

Comment: In my opinion an integer should be treated as an integer. Trying to be smart and rely on the compiler to fix bad programming is not okay. I think the 'boolean' and 'bool' problem have been fixed: "bool x = (bool) 23;" sets x to 1 and the same for boolean.

Comment: Personal opinions don't count. C and C++ are what they are. If you don't like it then program in visual basic.

Comment: Ha ha, visual basic. The 'c' and 'c++' is all about writing good code, because they allow to make a big mess of the code. Call it personal if you want to, I prefer code that shows what is going on. @user35336, Majenko has explained how it works, but we disagree if it is nice programming.

Comment: `if( x ){` in C/C++ reads "if x is not equal to zero". If `x` is numeric, that expression could be considered an idiomatic shorthand. If `x` represents a boolean, it reads quite naturally. Consider, f/ex, the character-class test `isdigit()`. Most people (in my experience) write `if( isdigit(x) ){`, not `if( isdigit(x) != 0 ){`; even though the latter states in explicit detail, what test is to be made. It comes to stylistic preference, and like discussions of which programming editor is "best", & what placement of braces or indentation is "best", rapidly devolves into a religious argument.

Comment: @JRobert Hence "personal opinions don't count". A personal opinion doesn't make something "bad", only "not the same as I think". My personal opinion is that all footballers are overpaid pansies. Does that make it true? I think so, but millions of football supporters disagree with me. Neither is right, neither is wrong, they are just opinions. And we don't like opinions on this site - hence we can close a question as "primarily opinion based". It'd be nice if we could do the same with comments ;) - but that's just an opinion :P

Comment: Thanks for taking my point and running with it! I couldn't have constructed a better example. :)

Comment: @Majenko, I take back the _"bad programming"_ and turn it into _"some use the fact that 'true' is everything but zero, as specified by the 'c' language. Others prefer to test the Serial.available against an integer to show that the function returns an integer"_. I think everyone is happy now.

Comment: For certain functions I agree, for others I don't. `if(!strcmp(...))` reads wrong. It looks like "if the strings don't match" when in fact they do. `if (strcmp(...) == 0)` is better in that instance. `if (Serial.available())` says"if there is some serial data available" which is fine. It's more to do with how it reads to the human eye than what type it returns.

Answer (score -1):

> Scenario A, it appears to me that there is no conditional statement, h

The first is a test on if available() returns a non zero value.